# Statistics Independence Question: Given that an item has passed inspection, what is the probability that it is actually flawed?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, independence

The problem I have a question about is below.  I only have a question on part (e), but I included the other parts of the question and answers as a reference.

**A quality control inspector is examining newly produced items for faults. The inspector searches an item for faults in a series of independent fixations, each of a fixed duration. Given that a flaw is actually present, let p denote the probability that the flaw is detected during any one fixation.**

**(a) Assuming that an item has a flaw, what is the probability that it is detected by the end of the second fixation (once a flaw has been detected, the sequence of fixations terminates)?**

Answer: $1-(1-p)^2$

**(b) Give an expression for the probability that a flaw will be detected by the end of the nth fixation.**

Answer: $1-(1-p)^n$

**(c) If when a flaw has not been detected in three fixations, the item is passed, what is the probability that a flawed item will pass inspection?**

Answer: $(1-p)^3$

**(d) Suppose 10% of all items contain a flaw [P(randomly chosen item is flawed) = 0.1]. With the assumption of part (c), what is the probability that a randomly chosen item will pass inspection (it will automatically pass if it is not flawed, but could also pass if it is flawed)?**

Answer: $0.90 + 0.10(1-p)^3$

**(e) Given that an item has passed inspection (no flaws in three fixations), what is the probability that it is actually flawed? Calculate for p = 0.4. (Round your answer to four decimal places.)**

My understanding of this problem is as follows:

Let $n = $ % of all items that contain a flaw

$n(1-p)^3\;=\;n(1-0.4)^3$

What would I set the equation to in order to solve for $n$?  Am I correct in my thinking, or am I completely off?

Comment: Something doesn't look right.  The probability of being flawed doesn't depend on the fact that it passed inspection.  For example if the flaw probability  $=0$, it will pass inspection.  However if the flaw probability is high, it will fail most of the time, but occasionally it will pass, even if flawed.

Comment: I agree.  I only set it up that way because in part (d), it states "Suppose 10% of all items contain a flaw."  Looking at the answer, I put $n$ where 0.10 is in part (d).  I have no clue if that is how you get the solution, that is just my best guess.  All of the other problems were based on the question before it, so I thought why not part (e) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ be the the probability that a part is flawed.  Then the probability that a part has passed inspection is $1-q+q(1-p)^3$, so the probability that this part is flawed is $\frac{q(1-p)^3}{1-q+q(1-p)^3}=0.01367$ for $q=0.1$ and $p=0.4$.

Comment: Just to add a little clarification to your answer... It took me a little while to fully understand why it was correct.  The numerator $q(1-p)^3$ is the probability that the part is flawed $q$ AND that the part isn't detected after 3 iterations $(1-p)^3$.  The denominator is the probability that ANY part, flawed or otherwise, passed an inspection after 3 iterations.  For some reason, all of this together didn't click with me at first, so I hope this helps to put it in layman terms for others like me that are pretty new to probability.

Comment: The equation computes to 0.0234375